# How to convert user input into a list and remove all occurrences of a particular digit or character?

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, raw-input

I assume I am tackling this problem from the wrong angles or lack the proper understanding of built-in functions and syntax to resolve my issues despite my trying. I also discovered using:

```
input("Enter input: ")
```

is dangerous and should use raw_input instead, but can't seem to get this functioning correctly.

I want to write a script that can take user input, convert it into a list, multiply each individual element by 3, scan the solution to that problem for any "3" and remove all occurences of "3" while maintaining all other figures in their respective elements in the list, to then print or return the final result.

ex. entering 1 2 3 would output 6 9 as 1 * 3 = 3 which would be omitted.
ex. entering 2 6 11 would output 6 18 as 11 * 3 = 33 and both 3's would be omitted.

If for instance, user was to input x where x * 3 = 2381193 - I want for this to be converted to 28119.

I believe the simplest way to do this would be to convert to a string?

I started with something like this:

```
userInput = input("list element seperated by space: ")
nums = userInput.split()
x = int(nums[0]) * 3
y = int(nums[1]) * 3
z = int(nums[2]) * 3
output = x, y, z
negate = list(output)
if "3" in str(x):
    del negate[0]
    if "3" in str(y):
        del negate[1]
            if "3" in str(z):
                del negate[2]
print(negate)
```

and now I've re-thought it to:

```
userInput = raw_input("list element seperated by space: ")
nums = userInput.split()

for x in list(nums):
numsList = int(x) * 3
output = list(numsList)

y = "3"
while y in str(output): output.remove(y)
print(output)
```

But overall, I am unable to achieve the desired result.

Could you please provide feedback?

It would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, your first snippet was close to making a solution to your problem. The only thing you would want to do, is to change the conditional statement into an interative statement, like so:

```
nums = str(input("list element seperated by space: ")).split(" ")
num_list = []
if len(nums) != 1:
    num_list = [*(int(num.replace("3", "")) * 3 for num in nums)]
else:
    num_list = [nums[0]]
for x in num_list:
    if x != 3:
        print(str(x).replace("3", "") + " ", end="")
    else:
        print("0 ", end="")
```

> If you input 11 you would receive 0 and if for instance you had 133 - you would want to remove the 3 but keep the 1.

This part of your question is not clear/elaborated enough hence i did not include this logic in my snippet above. So anyone is free to edit my answer and include it once the point above is clear.

[EDIT]: So i made changes to my snippet above. I have not tested this so there is a chance for it to be wrong. If that is the case, then inform me of any specific patterns/tests that would end as unwanted.

Comment: The output of your code would result in 111 222 333. I've since edited the OP for clarity.

Comment: The edited snippet gives me the following error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''  upon entering 1 2 3